# How to group products by attribute in product list?

Tags: product-list, sorting, product-collection

Is there a way to display products of category so that products are grouped by an attribute?

For example if we have a car parts shop and we want to display all parts that belong to certain car model and we want the products to be divided into sections by the type of the part (brakes, motor parts...). That way it would be easier for customers to scan the listing when the same type of products would be grouped together.

Comment: I think you dont need to go for attribute grouping to achieve this. Create subcategories for this...That will be the best option.

Comment: Hmm, just wondering if it is possible to list products from sub categories grouped in parent category's product list?

Comment: Answering to my own comment above, it is possible to list sub categories' products as grouped with the help of static blocks. First you create a static block that has widgets that list the appropriate sub categories' products. Then make the parent category to show only the static block and no products.

Comment: Happy to hear that you have resolved your problem. By reviewing this question again, I came to know that @pzirkind give you an excellent answer. So please accept that answer if it helped you or post your comment as a new answer and then accept your own answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following code:

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addCategoryFilter($categoryId)
                ->addAttributeToSort('atrribute_code', 'ASC')
                ->load();
```

So lets say you want to show a list of products in category 53 ascending by color, you would use this:

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addCategoryFilter(53)
                ->addAttributeToSort('color', 'ASC')
                ->load();
```

Once you have a sorted collection separating them on a list page can be done with the following code:

```
$oldValue = ''; // this will hold the old attribute value which we can compare to later
foreach($collection as $product){
    $newValue = $product->getColor(); // in this case we want to see if its a new color (but it can be any attribute)
    if(!$newValue == $oldValue){ // if it does not match the old value it means that this is the beginning of a new color, in other words a new section of products in this category
          echo '<h1>' . $newValue . ' Products</h1>'; // you can put whatever you want to show the separation vissually
          $oldValue = $newValue; // update the old value so all products with the same value will go here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was not what I was looking for. I need kind of sub headings to the product list and under each heading there would be group of products that have certain attribute set in product information.

Comment: @Webninja just updated the answer